# How to replace an entire array in a redux reducer while allowing application to re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In one of my application's reducers, I require to replace an entire array. Hence, I have written my reducer like this:

```
const arrayReducerDefaultState = []

const arrayReducer = (state = arrayReducerDefaultState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "CHANGE_ARRAY":
            return{
                ...state,
                array: action.array
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default arrayReducer
```

When the action is called, I see the array is being updated (using Redux Dev Tools). But the application does not render again when the 'array' value is updated.

How do I change my reducer so that I can keep replacing my entire array while allowing the application to re-render when the store changes.

EDIT 1:

```
    const arrayReducerDefaultState = {
    array: []
}

const arrayReducer = (state = arrayReducerDefaultState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "CHANGE_ARRAY":
            return {
                ...state,
                array: action.array
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Since I was having problems working with the default state being an array, I made it such that it is an object with an array in it. 'array' now is not undefined but changing it still does not re-render the application.

Comment: Your default state is an array, but your updated state is an object with a `.array` property. Which is the correct shape? If it's supposed to be an array, then the return should be `return action.array`

Comment: I tried that, exactly what @Андрей Брайтон solution says below. If I do that, 'array' becomes undefined even though I see the values in the Redux Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tour state is array, but you return object in `"CHANGE_ARRAY"` case.

```js
const arrayReducerDefaultState = []

const arrayReducer = (state = arrayReducerDefaultState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "CHANGE_ARRAY":
            return action.array
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default arrayReducer
```

Actually you can have mistake in selector.

*PS action has struct like object where must be type (required), payload (optinal) - there is you data, meta (optinal) - another additional inforamtion*

Comment: I changed my reducer to the one you have above. My 'array' state in the store is undefined even though I see the values in the Redux Dev Tools.  Do you have any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: Look at the action what you use. I suppose that you can get it only after handle action and in some case you return undefined

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works, but my problem was somewhere else.